# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll: 'Unable to load DLL 'kernel32.dll'

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

My computer is (lsb_release -a):

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
Release:    7.4.1708
Codename:   Core
```

and my dotnet core version (dotnet --version) is:

```
2.1.105
```

and my openssl version is:

```
openssl 
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
```

when I try to load my server I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.DllNotFoundException
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll: 'Unable to load DLL 'kernel32.dll': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.SafeHandles.SafeLibraryHandle.UnsafeNativeMethods.LoadLibraryEx(String lpFileName, IntPtr hFile, UInt32 dwFlags)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.SafeHandles.SafeLibraryHandle.Open(String filename)
```

My .csproj is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <NeutralLanguage>pt-BR</NeutralLanguage>
    <Authors>Cogtive Team</Authors>
    <Company>Cogtive Opex Software</Company>
    <Product>Cogtive Core Api V2</Product>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>false</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Cogtive.Core.Api.V2.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="2.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Cogtive.Core.Application\Cogtive.Core.Application.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`rpm -q openssl` returns:

```
openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
```

`rpm -qa | grep openssl` returns:

```
xmlsec1-openssl-1.2.20-7.el7_4.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
```

It was working fine until recently but now I can't make it work again.

my computer probably updated a library or something and now it's not working anymore.

any idea?

Comment: Can you share your `project.json` file content?

Comment: I have a project.assets.json but not a project.json. Is it the one you want to see?

Comment: `project.json` was a version 1.0 thing. The 2.0 equivalent is the `csproj` file.

Answer (score 0):

That OpenSSL version looks very surprsing. Here is what I have on CentOS:

```
[omajid@localhost ~]$ rpm -q openssl
openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
[omajid@localhost ~]$ openssl
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

Where did you get 1.1? Can you downgrade to 1.0? .NET Core is incompatible with 1.1.x: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9855

Comment: I read the issue. I am trying to downgrade to 1.0. but it's not working. any idea how I can downgrade? I am new on centOS. I downloaded (openssl-1.0.2o.tar.gzopenssl-1.0.2o.tar.gz) and I did `make install` but it didn't change the version.

Comment: What does `rpm -qa | grep openssl` say?

Comment: Okay. So the rpm output looks good. But somehow you have another version of openssl installed which might be getting picked up? Or maybe it's a red herring. Can you run an `strace`? Basically `strace -f -o strace.log dotnet run`? Do you see dotnet trying to open `libssl` at all? If so, which library is it opening?

Comment: it opens: 
open("/lib64/tls/libssl.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
open("/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libssl.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
open("/usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
open("/lib64/libssl3.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
open("/lib64/libssl.so.10", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>

Comment: This is really hard to parse. Any chance you could upload the strace log somewhere?

Comment: Sure!. strace: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WouZMB68viBNdSipaGQqfYA1XRTUZyEy. ltrace: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wVHZG0JIHGId5dD-LgFKhDYpAXU-C3UA

Comment: Hm. It looks like it opens the 1.0.2 openssl libraries. So the openssl version mismatch is probably unrelated to the kernel32 error.